# what are the databases windows phone 7,8 supports?

Tags: cordova

Actually i am developing an application for windows phone 7,8 and i want to use local storage as a temporary memory but it is causing an error so if anybody is having any idea regarding the same then please share with me.

Comment: pls accept ans if u got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phonegap data storage is not supported in windows phone.so u can go through below plugins .

A cordova 3 plugin implementing Web SQL Database for WP7 and WP8 is available at https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-websqldatabase. This plugin is based on the "Sql client for windows" with some modifications for bugfix (the fork is available on the same git repository).

A prototype for demonstration is available at https://github.com/Smile-SA/cordova-plugin-websqldatabase-proto.

Comment: I have tried web SQL also but it is not working for windows and in phonegap doc it is clearly given windows phone doesn't support web SQL The following platforms support WebSQL:

    Android
    BlackBerry 10
    iOS
    Tizen

Comment: but u can try below plugin for windows

Answer (score 1):

> windows phone not supported data storage in phonegap, but still i have
>   a hope to use below plugin.

```
 Did you try using : [Nokia community sqllite for windows phone][1]
```

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone%20?